Using SFDMU to migrate OwnerIds and handle inactive users
When using SFDMU to perform an upsert option, I want to preserve ownerids, but some of our records are owned by inactive users. I'd like to check the target org to see if the user is inactive there and then conditionally use either the original owner or the current user's id. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I've tried using a transformation, but it doesn't seem to change the OwnerIds.
"beforeUpdateAddons": [
                {
                    "module": "core:RecordsTransform",
                    "args": {
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "alias": "ownerIsActive",
                                "sourceObject": "User",
                                "sourceField": "IsActive",
                                "lookupSource": "target",
                                "lookupExpression": "source.Id == target.OwnerId"
                            }
                        ],
                        "transformations": [
                            {
                                "targetObject": "TargetObject__c",
                                "targetField": "OwnerId",
                                "formula": "formula.ownerIsActive ? target.OwnerId : null"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]

